# Can zookeeper cluster work if more than half zookeeper servers break down?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I have configed 3 zookeeper servers, Is there any way to let the cluster can work if 2 of them break down》

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** it cannot. Once the majority in the quorum is lost, it is implied as the complete failure of the quorum.

In this case of 3 member quorum, if one is lost still 2 remains to maintain the majority but in the event of losing 2, the majority making member in this 3-member quorum is lost which leads to unavailability of zookeeper service. The clients which attempt to connect with the zookeeper at this state would receive Connection Refused errors.

This is noted in the official Zookeeper [documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperOver.html),

> As long as a majority of the servers are available, the zookeeper service will be available.